# SQLite rounding timestamp up nearest 5 minute

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, timestamp, sql-timestamp

I have a table that has a timestamp column called 'time' and an integer column called 'number'. I want to do a query so that the timestamp is rounded up e.g. 2022/02/22 13:03:45 becomes 2022/02/22 13:05:00 and I also want to count the number of columns within the 5-minute interval and get an average 'number' within the 5-minute interval.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following may do what you wish :-

```
WITH cte /* Common Table Expression (like a temp  table) so conversion rounding just needs to be done once */ AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            time, /* original time column */
            number, /* original number column */
            ((strftime('%s',replace(time,'/','-')) / (5 * 60)) + 1) * (5 * 60) AS timevalue /* round up to 5 minute intervals */
        FROM example
    )
SELECT * /* Original and rounded Columns */
    , datetime(timevalue,'unixepoch')  AS roundedtime /* for demonstration of rounded date/time */
    , count(number) AS counted /* counted */
FROM cte 
GROUP BY timevalue; /* group for aggregation by 5 minute intervals */
```

- Noting that *and I also want to count the number of columns within the 5-minute interval* has been taken to be the **number of rows** rather than columns.
- It would be recommended to store the time in a recognised format which would thus negate the need to replace `/`s with `-`s.
- you may wish to refer to

  - https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html
  - https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html

The following demonstrates the above :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (time TEXT, number INTEGER);
INSERT INTO example VALUES ('2022/02/22 13:03:45',5)
,('2022/02/22 13:07:44',5)
    ,('2022/02/22 13:03:44',5)
    ,('2022/02/22 13:03:43',5)
    ,('2022/02/22 13:03:46',5)
    ,('2022/02/22 13:03:47',5)
    ,('2022/02/22 13:03:48',5)
    ,('2022/02/22 13:03:49',5)
    ,('2022/02/22 13:03:50',5)
    ,('2022/02/22 13:03:51',5)
    ,('2022/02/22 12:59:44',5)
;
/* SHOW ORIGINAL DATA */
SELECT * FROM example;

/* SHOW DESIRED RESULT */
WITH cte /* Common Table Expression (like a temp  table) so conversion rounding just needs to be done once */ AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            time, /* original time column */
            number, /* original number column */
            ((strftime('%s',replace(time,'/','-')) / (5 * 60)) + 1) * (5 * 60) AS timevalue /* round up to 5 minute intervals */
        FROM example
    )
/* SELECT *,(strftime('%s',replace(time,'/','-')) / (5 * 60)) * (5 * 60) AS timevalue, count(number) AS counter FROM example GROUP BY timevalue; */
SELECT * /* Original and rounded Columns */
    , datetime(timevalue,'unixepoch')  AS roundedtime /* for demonstration of rounded date/time */
    , count(number) AS counted /* counted */
FROM cte 
GROUP BY timevalue; /* group for aggregation by 5 minute intervals */
/* CLEANUP ENVIRONMENT */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example;
```

This results in :-

The source/original data :-

[image]

The Desired Result :-

[image]